# How to get value of Configuration parameter in teamcity using Gradle?

Tags: gradle, teamcity

I have been trying to get the value of configuration parameter since yesterday but no luck. On the documentation I can call it using this `teamcity["<property name>"]` but it wont work.

Say I have a configuration parameter called "isPaid". I want to get the "isPaid" param value in my gradle. How can I do that? Shouldn't that be

```
System.getProperty("teamcity[isPaid]")
```

Tried using both getProperty and getEnv but still did not work. Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Configuration parameters (no prefix) **are not passed into the build** and are only meant to share settings within a build configuration.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/configuring-build-parameters.html